# Setting body in iOS notifications seems to have no affect

Tags: ios, notifications, distriqt

We are using the Notifications ANE from 6/19/2016.

I'm trying to understand how "body" plays into iOS notifications with the ANE. If I do:

```
setAlert("My AlertText")
setTitle("My Title Text")
setBody("My Body Text")
```

On Android, I see all 3 and works great. on iOS, I only ever see the alert text and title text. I'm testing on an iPhone and iPod with iOS 9.3.5 and get the same behavior. I read the iOS documentation on notifications, reviewed their code examples and don't understand why, when I set body text in the notifications ANE, I don't see it. What do i see when all 3 are set is:

when the alert fires, I see:

- Application installation title
- my title text I set via the api.

When I go to see all the notifications, I see:

- my alert text I set via the api.
- my title text I set via the api.

No body text. Same behavior if message format is banner or alert.

What does body map to in iOS? I tried a test where I did NOT set title but only alert and body, when the message fires, I hear the beep but there is no alert and the notifications list is empty.

Can you explain the mapping of the ane to the ios notifications? or is this an iOS bug?

Thanks so much!

Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug but a limitation of iOS notifications.

iOS notifications don't have the concept of a `body` like on Android. There are only 2 text areas on iOS which are represented by the `alert` and `title` fields of a notification.